# Azure Stack App Services has no outbound IP

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-stack

I've run the suggested commands on the Kudu console to check for an outbound IP and nothing pops up.

[Evidence :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxJ7e.png)

Under properties within the App Services menu, no outbound IP is listed either.

[Evidence 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nUl1.png)

I did not setup this Azure Stack Account or this App Services Web App. I think it might have been set up in some "isolated" version. Is it possible to change some setting somewhere to allow an outbound IP? Should I just make a new Web App within the Service Plan? Should I make a new Service Plan?

Comment: I hope my answer is helpful to you, and I look forward to your reply.

Comment: As it turns out you don't need an outbound IP when connecting to a SQL Server on the same network as your Azure Stack environment. This was my main problem, sorry if my question didn't fully explain this as Azure Stack isn't very popular (for good reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **it's impossible to** change some setting somewhere to allow an outbound IP. For more details, pls read the offical document about [Inbound and outbound IP addresses in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips).

[image]

[The set of outbound IP addresses for your app changes when you scale your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-outbound-ips-change) between **the lower tiers (Basic, Standard, and Premium) and the Premium V2 tier**.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I came to the same conclusion after digging around in settings for several hours.